# tkinter travando na função

Tags: python, tkinter

to fazendo um mini-programinha para ser usado nas horas de trabalho/estudo estilo o método de pomodoro. Fiz bem simples, rapidinho, mas quando aperto para começar, o programa trava exatamente o tempo que foi colocado e só volta quando tudo terminou, para tentar achar o erro deixei com 3 segundos cada intervalo e tempo de serviço, ai ele fica parado até terminar tudo. Nisso tem algumas mudanças visuais que deveria ocorrer na tele, como mostrar os ciclos e que fase está, mas nada se mexe, e só volta quando tudo zera. Segue abaixo o código:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

# Action
def pomodoro():
    lb_acao['text'] = 'Pomodori'
    lb_acao['bg'] = 'red'
    qt_ciclos = int(ed_ciclos.get())

    while qt_ciclos >= 0:
        lb_ciclos_restantes['text'] = qt_ciclos
        sleep(3)

        lb_acao['text'] = 'Intervalo'
        lb_acao['bg'] = 'green'
        sleep(3)

        lb_acao['text'] = 'Pomodori'
        lb_acao['bg'] = 'red'

        qt_ciclos -= 1

win = Tk()

# Components
lb1 = Label(win, text='Tempo útil: ')
ed_tempo = Entry(win)

lb2 = Label(win, text='Tempo de intervalo: ')
ed_intervalo = Entry(win)

lb3 = Label(win, text='Quantidade de ciclos: ')
ed_ciclos = Entry(win)

btn = Button(win, text='Começar', command=pomodoro)

lb4 = Label(win, text='Ciclos restantes:')
lb_ciclos_restantes = Label(win, text='0')

lb5 = Label(win, text='Modo:')
lb_acao = Label(win, text='Preparado')

lb6 = Label(win, text='Tempo:')
lb_time = Label(win)

# GUI
lb1.grid(row=0, column=0)
ed_tempo.grid(row=0, column=1)

lb2.grid(row=1, column=0)
ed_intervalo.grid(row=1, column=1)

lb3.grid(row=2, column=0)
ed_ciclos.grid(row=2, column=1)

btn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)


lb4.grid(row=4, column=0)
lb_ciclos_restantes.grid(row=4, column=1)
lb5.grid(row=5, column=0)
lb_acao.grid(row=5, column=1)
lb6.grid(row=6, column=0)
lb_time.grid(row=6, column=1)

# Program
win.mainloop()
```

Então, isso é caracterista do tkinter, que não permite ficar mexendo em seu visual constantemente. Ou tem alguma coisa errada que não estou reparando?

Valeu....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece porque seu programa é síncrono. Isso quer dizer que ele só faz uma coisa de cada vez. Quando você chama `sleep`, o programa para de executar para dormir aquele determinado tempo, e enquanto está dormindo ele nem atualiza a tela e nem ouve a interface pra saber se o usuário deu algum comando; nisso, ele fica travado, apesar de voltar quando acaba o tempo de "dormida".

A solução é usar a função `after` do Tk. Você passa pra ela o número de milisegundos que quer esperar e uma função; o Tkinter então executa aquela função depois do dado número de milisegundos.

Isso significa que você tem então que dividir sua função `pomodoro` em algumas partes, para que possa esperar entre elas. Como também temos que lembrar em qual ciclo estamos em funções diferentes, adicionamos uma variável global. Aqui, chamei ela de `ciclo_atual`, e mantive os 3s de espera do código original:

```
from tkinter import *

# Quando o botão é clicado, resetamos o contador de ciclo atual
# e iniciamos o primeiro ciclo.
def pomodoro():
    global ciclo_atual
    ciclo_atual = 0
    iniciar_ciclo()

# Quando iniciamos um ciclo, verificamos se o contador extrapolou
# a quantidade de ciclos desejada. Se não, chamamos a função
# iniciar_intervalo depois de 3000 milisegundos.
def iniciar_ciclo():
    global ciclo_atual
    lb_acao['text'] = 'Pomodori'
    lb_acao['bg'] = 'red'
    qt_ciclos = int(ed_ciclos.get())
    lb_ciclos_restantes['text'] = qt_ciclos - ciclo_atual

    if ciclo_atual < qt_ciclos:
        ciclo_atual += 1
        win.after(3000, iniciar_intervalo)

# Ao iniciar o intervalo, atualizamos a interface e chamamos
# novamente a função iniciar_ciclo depois de 3000 ms.
def iniciar_intervalo():
    lb_acao['text'] = 'Intervalo'
    lb_acao['bg'] = 'green'
    win.after(3000, iniciar_ciclo)


win = Tk()

# Components
lb1 = Label(win, text='Tempo útil: ')
ed_tempo = Entry(win)

lb2 = Label(win, text='Tempo de intervalo: ')
ed_intervalo = Entry(win)

lb3 = Label(win, text='Quantidade de ciclos: ')
ed_ciclos = Entry(win)

btn = Button(win, text='Começar', command=pomodoro)

lb4 = Label(win, text='Ciclos restantes:')
lb_ciclos_restantes = Label(win, text='0')

lb5 = Label(win, text='Modo:')
lb_acao = Label(win, text='Preparado')

lb6 = Label(win, text='Tempo:')
lb_time = Label(win)

# GUI
lb1.grid(row=0, column=0)
ed_tempo.grid(row=0, column=1)

lb2.grid(row=1, column=0)
ed_intervalo.grid(row=1, column=1)

lb3.grid(row=2, column=0)
ed_ciclos.grid(row=2, column=1)

btn.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E)


lb4.grid(row=4, column=0)
lb_ciclos_restantes.grid(row=4, column=1)
lb5.grid(row=5, column=0)
lb_acao.grid(row=5, column=1)
lb6.grid(row=6, column=0)
lb_time.grid(row=6, column=1)

# Program
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nossa, bem legal, não conhecia está função do tkinter. Excelente, minha cambiara do sleep tava muita suspeita de ser o problema kkkk. Vou fazer umas coisas a mais nele, mas ta ai. O pessoal que quiser tornar suas tarefas mais produtivas, já tem um programinha pra deixar rolando enquanto trabalha/estudo. Valeu!